# Element UI including all components.Making large bundle size

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-component, element-ui

I was referring to following.

https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/quickstart#on-demand

So I followed instructions, But I am using class based components. So importing as following.

```
import {Checkbox} from 'element-ui';

@Component({
  components: { Checkbox
  }
})
export default class Work extends Vue {
}
```

But still bundle seems to be containing entire element ui, instead of only button component.

as when I run npm run build. it creates 800+ kb of vendor chunk. and that chunk was containing other component code (i.e. color-picker and all other)

They have mentioned to edit  .babelrc: as following:

```
{
  "presets": [["es2015", { "modules": false }]],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "component",
      {
        "libraryName": "element-ui",
        "styleLibraryName": "theme-chalk"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

But I am not using components globally as plugin. So I have not done that change.

How to reduce element ui bundle and to include only required components, making vendor chunks smaller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if we are not using our component globally as plugin we need babel settings. As I mistaken their statement that these are only applicable for global plugin as examples were using `Vue.use(Pagination);`.

It works with babel config as following in babel.config.js.

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@vue/app'
  ],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "component",
      {
        "libraryName": "element-ui",
        "styleLibraryName": "theme-chalk"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

and to install following package.
npm install babel-plugin-component -D